# How to pass user detail information into a modal

Tags: reactjs, function, react-context, simplemodal

I have compiled a project with context. Crud operations work here without problems. However, there is such a problem that when you click on the info button (eye), the detailed information of that user is not visible in the opened modal. What is the problem

```html
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import {  Modal } from "antd";
import InfoIcon from "../assets/icons/InfoIcon";
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import { useContext } from "react";
import { GlobalContext } from "../context/GlobalState";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const InfoModal = () => {

  const { contacts } = useContext(GlobalContext);

  const [contactInfo, SetContactInfo] = useState({
    id: "",
    name: "",
    surname: "",
    fatherName: "",
    specialty: "",
    email: "",
    gender: "",
    test:''
  });

  const { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    const userId = id;
    const contactInfo = contacts.find((user) => user.id === userId);
    if (contactInfo) {
      SetContactInfo(contactInfo);
    }
  }, [id, contacts]);

  

  const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false);

  const showModal = () => {
    setIsModalVisible(true);
    console.log(contactInfo);
  };

  const handleOk = () => {
    setIsModalVisible(false);
  };

  const handleCancel = () => {
    setIsModalVisible(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={showModal}>
      <InfoIcon></InfoIcon>
      </div>
      <Modal
        title="Basic Modal"
        visible={isModalVisible}
        onOk={handleOk}
        onCancel={handleCancel}
      >
        <p>{contactInfo.email}</p>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
};

export default InfoModal;
```

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dMKd.png)

Comment: maybe contactInfo is null or undefined

Comment: probably no, cause contactİnfo seen in the console, just the values are not passed, for example name:"", email:""

Comment: show the structure of your contacts data which is you are using in the contacts.find ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/vymm1d i added projects sandbox, please review

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a param from url and you check for strict equality "===", your userId is a string and you try to compare with an integer, you can try this:

```
const contactInfo = contacts.find((user) => user.id === parseInt(userId));
```

or

```
const contactInfo = contacts.find((user) => user.id == userId);
```

Comment: sorry, it doesnt work again

Comment: Can you make a console .log of contactInfo ? Just to be sure there is some data in it

Comment: İadded picture log. I think that each button should be given an id or a key, when the button is clicked, the information of the contact corresponding to that id should be displayed in the modal

Comment: Ok so in the picture I see that all the props in the object have empty values, so this is normal that your modal is empty, you have to be sure to get something in contactInfo, this is your problem

Comment: how can i do this
I want to see contact information in the modal that opens when I click on the button of a contact.
I have added the sandbox link top comment, if possible, you can take a look