# How prevent submit edit form when anything is not changed?

Tags: reactjs, forms, submit, crud, func

I have a form like this that I created with context crud project. Here I want that if no changes have been made in the form, it should not be updated and a notification should be issued. How can I do this?
Note: also, if any input is empty, do not submit. How can I do this without required the input. How can I fix these problems?

```html
import React from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { GlobalContext } from "../../context/GlobalState";
import styles from "../ContactForm/Form.module.scss";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
const EditContactForm = () => {
  const { contacts, UPDATE_CONTACT } = useContext(GlobalContext);

  const [selectedContact, setSelectedContact] = useState({
    id: "",
    name: "",
    surname: "",
    fatherName: "",
    specialty: "",
    email: "",
    gender: "",
    test:''
  });
  const history = useNavigate();

  const { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    const userId = id;
    const selectedContact = contacts.find((user) => String(user.id) === userId);
    if (selectedContact) {
      setSelectedContact(selectedContact);
    }
  }, [id, contacts]);

  function onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(selectedContact){
    UPDATE_CONTACT(selectedContact);
    console.log("new user edited:", selectedContact);
    history("/contacts");
    toast('updated')
    }
    else if(selectedContact===contacts){
      toast('anything doesnt changed') // problem is there
    }
  }

  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    setSelectedContact((selectedContact) => ({
      ...selectedContact,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    }));
  };

  const inputHandleChange = (e) => {
    setSelectedContact({
      ...selectedContact,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.checked ? e.target.id : "",
    });
  };

  const selectOptions = [
    { label: "One", value: 1 },
    { label: "Two", value: 2 },
    { label: "Three", value: 3 },
  ];
  const onChange = (e) => setSelectedContact({ ...selectedContact, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  return (
    <div className={styles.form}>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <div class="mb-3 row row d-flex justify-content-around">
          <label className={`col-sm-2 p-0 ${styles.inputLabel}`}>Name</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input
              class="form-control"
              name="name"
              required
              value={selectedContact?.name ?? ""}
              onChange={handleOnChange}
            />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3 row row d-flex justify-content-around">
          <label className={`col-sm-2 p-0 ${styles.inputLabel}`}>Surname</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input
              class="form-control"
              name="surname"
              required
              value={selectedContact?.surname ?? ""}
              onChange={handleOnChange}
            />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3 row row d-flex justify-content-around">
          <label className={`col-sm-2 p-0 ${styles.inputLabel}`}>
            Father Name
          </label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input
              class="form-control"
              name="fatherName"
              required
              value={selectedContact?.fatherName ?? ""}
              onChange={handleOnChange}
            />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3 row row d-flex justify-content-around">
          <label className={`col-sm-2 p-0 ${styles.inputLabel}`}>Email</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input
              class="form-control"
              name="email"
              required
              value={selectedContact?.email ?? ""}
              onChange={handleOnChange}
            />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3 row row d-flex justify-content-around">
          <label className={`col-sm-2 p-0 ${styles.inputLabel}`}>
            Specialty
          </label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input
              class="form-control"
              name="specialty"
              required
              value={selectedContact?.specialty ?? ""}
              onChange={handleOnChange}
            />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="mb-3 row row d-flex justify-content-around">
          <label className={`col-sm-2 p-0 ${styles.inputLabel}`}>position</label>
          <div className="col-sm-8 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
          <select
            onChange={onChange}
            value={selectedContact.test}
            name="test"
            class="form-select"
            aria-label="Default select example"
          >
            {selectOptions.map((item) => (
              <option 
              key={item.value} 
              value={item.value}
              >
              {item.label}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="mb-3 row row d-flex justify-content-around">
          <label className={`col-sm-2 p-0 ${styles.inputLabel}`}>Gender</label>
          <div className="col-sm-8">
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline ">
              <input
                class="form-check-input"
                type="radio"
                name="gender"
                id="male"
                checked={selectedContact.gender === "male"}
                onChange={inputHandleChange}
              />
              <label class="form-check-label">Male</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input
                class="form-check-input"
                type="radio"
                name="gender"
                id="female"
                checked={selectedContact.gender === "female"}
                onChange={inputHandleChange}
              />
              <label class="form-check-label">Female</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="mb-3 row d-flex justify-content-around">
          <div class="form-check col-sm-11">
            <input
              class="form-check-input"
              type="checkbox"
              name="updatesNotification"
              id="update"
              checked={selectedContact.updatesNotification === "update"}
              onChange={(e) =>
                setSelectedContact({
                  ...selectedContact,
                  [e.target.name]: e.target.checked ? e.target.id : "",
                })
              }
            />
            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
              I want to be notified of updates
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className={styles.buttons}>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            Update a contact
          </button>
          <NavLink to="/contacts" className="btn btn-danger m-2">
            Cancel
          </NavLink>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default EditContactForm;
```

```html
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { GlobalContext } from "../../context/GlobalState";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import styles from "../ContactForm/Form.module.scss";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import { Checkbox, Button, Form, Input, Select, Radio } from "antd";

const Form1 = () => {
  const { ADD_CONTACT } = useContext(GlobalContext);
  const [contact, setContact] = useState({
    id: uuidv4(),
    name: "",
    surname: "",
    fatherName: "",
    specialty: "",
    email: "",
    gender: "",
    updatesNotification: "",
    test: "",
  });

  const { Option } = Select;

  const { name, surname, fatherName, specialty, email } = contact;

  let history = useNavigate();

  const onSubmit = () => {
    if (contact) {
      ADD_CONTACT(contact);
      history("/contacts");
      console.log(contact);
      toast.success("Contact successfully added");
    }
     else{
       ???
    }

  };

  const selectOptions = [
    { label: "One", value: 1 },
    { label: "Two", value: 2 },
    { label: "Three", value: 3 },
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <Form
        onFinish={onSubmit}
        className={styles.form}
        name="myForm"
        initialValues={{
          remember: true,
        }}
        autoComplete="off"
        labelCol={{
          span: 2,
        }}
        wrapperCol={{
          span: 16,
        }}
      >
        <div className="row">
          <Form.Item
            label="Name"
            rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please input your name!" }]}
          >
            <Input
              placeholder="Enter Your Name"
              value={name}
              name="name"
              onChange={(e) =>
                setContact({ ...contact, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
              }
            />
          </Form.Item>
        </div>

        <Form.Item
          label="Surname"
          rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please input your surname!" }]}
        >
          <Input
            placeholder="Enter Your Surname"
            value={surname}
            name="surname"
            onChange={(e) =>
              setContact({ ...contact, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
            }
          />
        </Form.Item>

        <Form.Item
          label="Father Name"
          rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please input your surname!" }]}
        >
          <Input
            placeholder="Enter Your FatherName"
            value={fatherName}
            name="fatherName"
            onChange={(e) =>
              setContact({ ...contact, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
            }
          />
        </Form.Item>

        <Form.Item
          label="Email"
          rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please input your mail!" }]}
        >
          <Input
            name="email"
            placeholder="your mail"
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) =>
              setContact({ ...contact, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
            }
          />
        </Form.Item>

        <Form.Item
          label="Specialty"
          rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please input your specialty!" }]}
        >
          <Input
            name="specialty"
            placeholder="your specialt"
            value={specialty}
            onChange={(e) =>
              setContact({ ...contact, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
            }
          />
        </Form.Item>

        <Form.Item label='Category'>
          <Select
            onChange={(e)=>setContact({ ...contact, test : e })}
            defaultValue='category'
            // value={contact.test}
            name="test"
            style={{
              width: 120,
            }}
          >
            {selectOptions.map((item) => (
              <Option key={item.value} value={item.value}></Option>
            ))}
          </Select>
        </Form.Item>

        <Form.Item label="Gender">
          <Radio.Group
            onChange={(e) =>
              setContact({
                ...contact,
                [e.target.name]: e.target.checked ? e.target.id : "",
              })
            }
            name="gender"
            rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please  your gender!" }]}
          >
            <Radio
              id="female"
              value="Female"
              checked={contact.gender === "female"}
            >
              Female
            </Radio>
            <Radio id="male" value="Male" checked={contact.gender === "male"}>
              Male
            </Radio>
          </Radio.Group>
        </Form.Item>

        <Form.Item>
          <Checkbox
            name="updatesNotification"
            checked={contact.updatesNotification === "update"}
            id="update"
            onChange={(e) =>
              setContact({
                ...contact,
                [e.target.name]: e.target.checked ? e.target.id : "",
              })
            }
          >
            I want to be notified of updates
          </Checkbox>
        </Form.Item>

        <div className={styles.buttons}>
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
            Add contact
          </Button>
          <NavLink to="/contacts">
            <Button danger>Cancel</Button>
          </NavLink>
        </div>
      </Form>
    </>
  );
};

export default Form1;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FYLe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to check if two objects are equal is to transform them into string.

```
JSON.stringify(selectedContact) === JSON.stringify(contacts.find((user) => user.id === selectedContact.id))
```

For checking if one if the data is empty one way is using the method some, this method send true if one the item in an array match the condition.

```
    if (Object.keys(selectedContact).some(key => !selectedContact[key])) {
    alert('There are missing information')
}
```

Comment: sorry, it doesnt work, it seems we are not doing the comparison correctly

Comment: And are you sure your selectedContact and contacts are build in the same way ? What do you have when you console.log the two objects ?

Comment: oh yes, selectedContact ={} one object which i select , but contacts is array which all objects inside. How i defines contacts id equal to that selected contact JSON.stringify(selectedContact) === JSON.stringify(contacts[id])

Comment: Do you have something in your contacts variable when you console.log it ?

Comment: i added log picture,  log(selectedContact) and log(contacts)

Comment: I edited my code, I hope it will help

Comment: thank you so muchh, last questionn how can I prevent this if the input is empty while adding

Comment: Yesterday i asked question for info modal here, can you help me for that question?

Comment: Do you have a link to that question ?

Comment: yes sir, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73474453/how-to-pass-user-detail-information-into-a-modal